# Retrieving a limited number of direct messages from Twitter

Tags: android, twitter

How can I get a limited number of direct messages from Twitter?

The Twitter API `getDirectMessages()` call gives all the messages, but I just want a limited number. For example, top 50.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't ask us how to use someone else's api, ask Twitter. This is not a programming question.

Comment: @Dan There are a lot of questions about using specific frameworks and APIs here. They are on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Twitter documentation at: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/direct_messages the `directMessages` call accepts an optional parameter, `count`, that determines the number of direct messages to be returned.  They provide an example request:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1/direct_messages.json?count=1&page=1
```

Comment: visceralG, thanks for the reply,
I tries this using paging
>>Paging paging = new Paging(1,1); // paging(page,count)
>>List<DirectMessage> messages = twitter.getDirectMessages(paging);

but still its giving all the messages.

Comment: Bingo, problem solved. Don't know what was the problem, but it running perfectly using paging :)